# How to call a detail view from a table view within a Storyboard

Tags: iphone

I have following problem.

I have created a tab based Application with three Views and Viewcontroller. 
FirstView(Start screen stuff), SecondView (Detailpage), ThirdView (Table for listing items). 
(Connections from storyboard were set automatically).

In the third view a table is integrated and the content is displayed fine.

Now I would like to call the SecondView , when a row in the table is selected.

I also tried to add a forth View , outside the tabBar Controller, to get the Detailview, but this also did not help.

I have tried several tutorials and forum tips, but cannot get it working.

The class is set to the right ViewController, the identifier is set to detail.

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
DetailViewController *detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detail"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
detail.label1.text = @"It is working";
```

}

When clicking on the row, it becomes blue, but nothing happens. No error Message , nothing.

Hope that you can help :-)

---

OK, I have tried to "optimize" my design.

Still have the tab based Views, but when clicking on a row in the table, a new (not linked in Storyboard) view should appear to display the details of the selected quote.

1. I have created a view in the storyboard and called it "detailzitat"
2. I have created a DetailViewController.h/m as UIViewcontroller class
3. I have set the custom class to DetailViewController
4. I import the DetailViewController.h in the ThirdViewController.h

I have modified the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method in ThirdViewController.h accordingly.

```
 -(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
DetailViewController *detailVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detailzitat"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailVC animated:YES];
```

}

and my DetailViewController.m looks like

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"
@implementation DetailViewController
@synthesize label1, labeltext;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
labeltext=@"JUHU";
label1.text=labeltext;
}
```

But again, nothing happens, besides the row gets blue.

I do not understand. If I am using this code in a Non-Storyboard project, it is working. 
What am I doing wrong ? Is there any tutorial for this combination within Storyboards ? Have not found one for this approach yet. 
Try to learn from the different tutorials on the web, but the biggest problem is, most ones are not for iOS5 and I am not so good to transfer then.

Hope to get some hints :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to think about your design. If I am understanding your description correctly, the user will be on the third tab, tap on a row in a table, and then you will be switching them back to the second tab. A navigation controller might be a more natural, less confusing, choice there.

But in any case, something like this will work **sometimes**:

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    DetailViewController *detailVC = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];

    detailVC.label1.text = @"It is working"; // <- this will not work consistently!

    self.tabBarController.selectedViewController = detailVC; 

}
```

The problem with this is that while the user is on that third tab, it's possible that the second tab view controller's view is unloaded (due to memory pressure for example).

It's also possible the user went from tab 1 to tab 3 immediately and therefore the 2nd tab's view isn't even loaded yet at all. (To even test the above code you would have to select tab 2 and then tab 3.)

If the second tab's view hierarchy is not loaded, the label1 property will be nil, and so this will not work. A better strategy would be to create a new @property of type NSString* on the DetailViewController. And set **that** property instead of trying to set the label1 directly.

Then in your `viewWillAppear:` for the DetailViewController you can update your labels as needed. At that point of course you can be sure that label1 is loaded and connected to the correct UILabel.

I hope that helps.

Comment: First of all "Thanks" :-) You made my day . Ok, the problem is , to try to map the different tutorials to put things together I think ;-)) However, I am just trying and figuring out, how things are working.   And my "approach" of the app is following. Having a app for quotes.   In the "2nd View" you can get randomized quotes, and the view is formatted for displaying a quote.  In the "3rd View" , you will have a table with all quotes listed. And if you click on a row , the "DetailView/2nd View" should appear. Do you have any suggestions for a better solution not layouting twice the same view?

Comment: You're welcome, of course. You might consider a UINavigationController with the Detail View as its root and button on the DetailView that pushes the full list of quotes. Or perhaps a flip "utility"-style presentation. Or even just present the list modally. Just something to give the user some context of what's happening. I think I would be confused personally with hopping tabs. Anyway, just my $0.02 since SO is probably not the best place for design advice. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is at self.navigationController. If your view is not inside the navigation controller this will not work. So what you do is create a new navigation controller object there and then use it to show your detail view.